# Should I initialize the SecureRandom for my BCryptPasswordEncoder with a seed?

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt, secure-random

I am just doing a code review of a co-workers task and came across the following lines of code (he was implementing a Spring Security based login system).

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(ENCODING_STRENGTH, new SecureRandom(SEED_BYTES));
}
```

Is it a good idea to initialize this particular `SecureRandom` with a constant seed? I don't think so, but can't really explain why.

Comment: No need for seed. In Java 8 use `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html):

> Additionally, SecureRandom must produce non-deterministic output. Therefore any seed material passed to a SecureRandom object must be unpredictable, and all SecureRandom output sequences must be cryptographically strong, as described in *RFC 1750: Randomness Recommendations for Security*.

If your `SEED_BYTES` is a constant, it is predictable.

`BCryptPasswordEncoder` uses the cryptographically strong `SecureRandom` only to generate the salt, see [`BCrypt#gensalt`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html#gensalt-int-java.security.SecureRandom-):

> random - an instance of SecureRandom to use

That leads to predictable salts.

The salt should be (at best) unique, see [A Future-Adaptable Password Scheme](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node3.html):

> As proposed by Morris and Thompson [9], however, lookup tables can be thwarted with the second input to F, which they call a salt. If a random salt is chosen whenever users establish new passwords, and if the salt space is large enough to ensure a negligible probability of recurrence, lookup tables offer an adversary no advantage; he may as well compute F at the time of attack. If, on the other hand, the salt space is too small, the output bits of F become useful predicates on passwords, a fact exploited by the QCrack [12] program described in Section 6.

If you use a constant seed, you will get the same sequence of salts after every restart of your application. That leads to [salt collisions](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node12.html#SECTION00062100000000000000).

A salt collision and a predictable salt weaken your security, see [Seven Ways To Screw Up BCrypt](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html):

> **#1: Using A Non-Random Salt**
>
> [...] If the salt for any two hashes is the same, then the attacker can re-use the computation to attack both at the same time (for brute force style attacks). [...]
>
> **#2: Using An Incorrect Random Source for Salt Generation**
>
> [...] Additionally, some of the weak random sources suffer from problems known as "seed poisoning" where an attacker can effect future generated randomness.